# Create date dimension in Azure synapse analytics

Tags: sql-server, azure, stored-procedures, azure-synapse

I use 2 stored procedures to create a date_dimension in Synapse. First proc to create the details of a year and the second proc to iterate over it to create a range of years via a copy activity.

The second proc has 2 import parameters as YearStart=2000 and YearEnd=2030. However when I execute the copy activity it only creates the date table **only** for **one year (2000)** and it seems the loop doesn't work!

Here is the second proc.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [PopulateDateDimensionForYearRange] @YearStart [int], @YearEnd [int] 
AS

BEGIN
    DECLARE @CurrentYear INT
    SET @CurrentYear = @YearStart
    WHILE @CurrentYear IS NOT NULL AND @YearStart <= @YearEnd AND @CurrentYear <= @YearEnd
    BEGIN
        EXEC PopulateDateDimensionForYear @Year = @CurrentYear;
        SET @CurrentYear  = @CurrentYear  + 1   
    END;
END;
```

As you can see the first proc name is `PopulateDateDimensionForYear`  which I call it in the second proc and it works perfectly. Since the details of that only one year is correct.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [PopulateDateDimensionForYear] @Year [int] AS

BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#month', 'U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #month
    CREATE TABLE #month (
        monthnum int,
        numofdays int
    )
    INSERT INTO #month
        SELECT 1, 31 UNION SELECT 2, CASE WHEN (@YEAR % 4 = 0 AND @YEAR % 100 <> 0) OR @YEAR % 400 = 0 THEN 29 ELSE 28 END UNION SELECT 3,31 UNION SELECT 4,30 UNION SELECT 5,31 UNION SELECT 6,30 UNION SELECT 7,31 UNION SELECT 8,31 UNION SELECT 9,30 UNION SELECT 10,31 UNION SELECT 11,30 UNION SELECT 12,31

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#days', 'U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #days
    CREATE TABLE #days (days int)

    INSERT INTO #days
        SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12 UNION SELECT 13 UNION SELECT 14 UNION SELECT 15 UNION SELECT 16 UNION SELECT 17 UNION SELECT 18 UNION SELECT 19 UNION SELECT 20    UNION SELECT 21 UNION SELECT 22 UNION SELECT 23 UNION SELECT 24 UNION SELECT 25 UNION SELECT 26 UNION SELECT 27 UNION SELECT 28 UNION SELECT 29 UNION SELECT 30 UNION SELECT 31

    SELECT
        CAST(CAST(monthnum AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' + CAST([days] AS VARCHAR(3)) + '/' + CAST(@year AS CHAR(4)) AS DATE) AS [Date]
        ,DAY(CAST(CAST(monthnum AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' + CAST([days] AS VARCHAR(3)) + '/' + CAST(@year AS CHAR(4)) AS DATE)) AS [Day]
        ,CAST(DATENAME(month, CAST(CAST(monthnum AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' + CAST([days] AS VARCHAR(3)) + '/' + CAST(@year as char(4)) AS DATE)) AS nvarchar(10)) AS [MonthName]
        ,MONTH(CAST(CAST(monthnum as varchar(2)) + '/' + CAST([days] as varchar(3)) + '/' + CAST(@year as char(4)) AS DATE)) AS [MonthNumber]
        ,CAST(N'CY' + CAST(YEAR(CAST(CAST(monthnum as varchar(2)) + '/' + CAST([days] as varchar(3)) + '/' + CAST(@year as char(4)) AS DATE)) AS nvarchar(4)) + N'-' + SUBSTRING(DATENAME(month, CAST(CAST(monthnum as varchar(2)) + '/' + CAST([days] as varchar(3)) + '/' + CAST(@year as char(4)) AS DATE)), 1, 3) AS nvarchar(10)) AS [CalendarMonthLabel]
        ,YEAR(CAST(CAST(monthnum as varchar(2)) + '/' + CAST([days] as varchar(3)) + '/' + CAST(@year as char(4)) AS DATE)) AS [Year]
        , DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, CAST(CAST(monthnum as varchar(2)) + '/' + CAST([days] as varchar(3)) + '/' + CAST(@year as char(4)) AS DATE)) AS [ISOWeekNumber]
FROM #month m
    CROSS JOIN #days d
WHERE d.days <= m.numofdays

DROP table #month;
DROP table #days;
END;
```

Does someone know how to make it happen for all the years in the range?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You would need to post the code for proc `PopulateDateDimensionForYear` as well please.

Comment: I tried your code and the result seem to be right. [ScreenShoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSKe2.png).

Comment: And how are you calling it from Synapse Pipelines?  I would guess you have hard-typed the parameters somewhere.  Also note, none of this code inserts data into any date dimension - are you doing that as part of the Sink activity?  If these objects are in the same database as the date dimension I would just use a Stored Proc task not a Copy activity to do this.

Comment: @wBob in a copy activity I chose stored procedure as source and from there I chose the second proc to execute, also there clicking on IMPORT PARAMETERS it will automatically recognize the parameters and I only set their values.

Comment: @Ehsan Sorry , I'm using Azure SQL. Let me try in Azure Synapse.

Comment: Please add two screenprints from the pipeline, one showing the detail from the Source tab of the Copy activity and one showing the detail from the Sink tab.

Comment: @Ehsan I got the same result in Azure Synapse with dedicated SQL pool. Using SSMS.

Comment: NB I had to fix up my range statement which should be `@range(2000,30)`.

Comment: Some teamwork there @JosephXu?  : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end I came up with an idea from @wBob's answer. I put it below.

Basically what I needed was that to modify the second proc as follow:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [PopulateDateDimensionForYearRange] @YearStart [int], @YearEnd [int] AS

BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#date_dimension', 'U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #date_dimension
    CREATE TABLE #date_dimension (
        Date Date,
        Day int,
        MonthName VARCHAR(30),
        MonthNumber int,
        CalendarMonthLabel VARCHAR(30),
        Year int,
        ISOWeekNumber int
    )

    DECLARE @CurrentYear INT
    SET @CurrentYear = @YearStart
    WHILE @CurrentYear IS NOT NULL AND @YearStart <= @YearEnd AND @CurrentYear <= @YearEnd
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #date_dimension EXEC PopulateDateDimensionForYear @Year = @CurrentYear;
        SET @CurrentYear  = @CurrentYear  + 1   
    END;
    SELECT * FROM #date_dimension 
    DROP TABLE #date_dimension
END;
```

The rest is completely the same as before, in my copy activity!

Answer (score 2):

Your second proc returns multiple resultsets so will not work with the Copy activity.  You have a few options: 1) change your second proc to `SELECT INTO` a temp table, and then `INSERT` into your main date dimension and call it with a Stored Proc activity:

```
    SELECT
        ...
INTO #tmp
FROM #month m
    CROSS JOIN #days d
WHERE d.days <= m.numofdays


INSERT yourDateDim
SELECT * FROM #tmp
```

OR change your process to use a For Each loop with the 'range' function to generate your years:

```
@range(2000,30)
```

[image]

Azure Synapse does not support `INSERT ... EXEC` but there is a workaround described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-temporary).

Comment: What is the activity in FOREACH?

Comment: Stored Proc activity.  ie not the loop one.  Pass in the year parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your help but what I dont understand is that where are the results saved? I mean in a copy activity I copy the the years in a dataset but here I just run the Proc 30 times !!!

Comment: What I do is that I create a file out of the proc and then create a view on it. So later I can use that view in powerBI as a date_dimension

Comment: Change the stored proc to actually insert the data or use Copy activity inside the loop, similar to what you were doing originally.